# Changing div position with SEO text inside in the html preserving its position in the layout

Tags: html, css

Here is the site I am currently supporting http://www.2k.ua/restaurants/catalog/

If you scroll down to the bottom of the page you will see the SEO text right before the footer.

The site owners are asking me change the position of the SEO text in the html code, to put in right after the opening   tag but not changing its position in the layout (by this I mean it must stay where it is now in the layout but not in the html code).

Could someone explain me please if it is possible? Something like position: absolute or fixed I dont think will resolve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "by this I mean it must stay where it is now in the layout but not in the html code" Without HTML Code?? Are you sure you mean this?? And what do you mean when you say "right before the opening tag"??

Comment: Sorry about that - I edited the question. I meant after the opening <body> tag

Comment: "by this I mean it must stay where it is now in the layout but not in the html code" Without HTML Code?? Are you sure you mean this?? I mean that I can change the html code to put the SEO text in other place but visually it must not change, it must stay where it i s now